# drawable vector not working (android studio)

Tags: xml, android-studio

I tryed to add a FloatingActionButton to my app but it doesnt display the drawable victor i created

my code :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/back_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/go_top" /
```

[and here is an image of the button in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSho.jpg)

as you can see in the image the vector i have created is not there its just the circle

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: which theme you are using in this activity?

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing something
Add this gradle files in app level gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
```

add this to build.gradle

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

and in layout use directly src

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/submit"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Comment: i have done it but it did not work 
so i tried using an image button and it worked :)
thanks anyway